# keep looping after finish calculation

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double a, b, c, Result;
        while (true) // and is  good idea to use while to keep backing to main ??
        {
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCalcualtor");
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t----------");
            Console.WriteLine("put Number Plz");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("put other Number Plz");
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Choose :*,+,-,/");
            string uservalue = Console.ReadLine();
            if (uservalue == "*")
            {
                Result = a * b;
                Console.Write("Resultat= " + a * b);
            }
            else if (uservalue == "+")
            {
                Result = a + b;
                Console.Write("Resultat= " + (a + b));
            }
            else if (uservalue == "-")
            {
                Result = a - b;
                Console.Write("Resultat= " + (a - b));
            }
            else if (uservalue == "/")
            {
                Result = a / b;
                Console.Write("Resultat= " + (a / b));
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("put right operator !!!");
```

// i need here to start all over whats i did before mean loop im still new with c# any suggestions?

```
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

}

well this question I ask it time ago and I was don't know much about c# so I already solve it

Comment: I don't see a question yet, just a bunch of code. Also, don't use `goto`

Comment: question is after else i need back to console uservalue so how i do thats ???

Comment: That's not really a coherent question. You already print the result of the calculation...

Comment: Unclear what you want. Please try to explain better. I don't understand what  "i need back to the uservalue console" means.

Comment: if user enter other than *,/,+,- i need he have chance to write again *,/,+,- to program keep working

Comment: Ok.... you know that `while` loop you have at the top? You need another one with an actual condition instead of `true`.

Comment: Just picture yourself being the program asking your friend for input - would you explain *everthing* all over if he didn't name the right operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its work now perfect

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double a, b,Result;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCalcualtor");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t----------");
            Console.WriteLine("put Number Plz");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("put other Number Plz");
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Choose :*,+,-,/");
            bool successful;
            do
            {
                string uservalue = Console.ReadLine();
                if (uservalue == "*")
                {
                    Result = a * b;
                    Console.Write("Resultat= " + a * b);
                    successful = true;
                }
                else if (uservalue == "+")
                {
                    Result = a + b;
                    Console.Write("Resultat= " + (a + b));
                    successful = true;
                }
                else if (uservalue == "-")
                {
                    Result = a - b;
                    Console.Write("Resultat= " + (a - b));
                    successful = true;
                }
                else if (uservalue == "/")
                {
                    Result = a / b;
                    Console.Write("Resultat= " + (a / b));
                    successful = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("put right operator !!!");
                    successful = false ;
                }


               } 
            while (!successful);
            {
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            }

           }
       }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeking for a completely newbie solution, you may want to raise a flag on successful operation, and wrap operator input into another loop:

```
bool successful;
do
{
    string uservalue = Console.ReadLine();
    if (uservalue == "*")
    {
        Result = a * b;
        Console.Write("Resultat= " + a * b);
        successful = true;
    }
    //other operators
    else
        Console.WriteLine("put right operator !!!");
} while (!successful)
```

Also I would recommend switch/case sonstruction, like that:

```
string uservalue = Console.ReadLine();
switch (uservalue)
{
    case "*":
        Console.Write("Resultat= " + (a * b));
        break;
    //other operators
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("put right operator !!!");
        break;
}
```

**P.S.:** you're calculating your values twice, once when assigning a value to the variable "Result", and second one when outputting a string, if you already have the value in your variable, you should call `Console.Write("Resultat= " + Result);`

Comment: i well try add thats to my code  i appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I would create functions to read user input:

```
static double GetNumber(string prompt) {
    double answer;
    Console.WriteLine(prompt);
    while (true) {
        if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answer)) {
            return answer;
        }
       Console.WriteLine("Error: Try again");
    }
}
static string GetOperator(string prompt) {
    string answer;
    Console.WriteLine(prompt);
    while (true) {
        answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if ("*/+-".Contains(answer)) {
            return answer;
        }
       Console.WriteLine("Error: Try again");
    }
}
```

Then your main becomes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCalcualtor");
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t----------");
        double a = GetNumber("put Number Plz");
        double b = GetNumber("put other Number Plz");
        string uservalue = GetOperator("Choose :*,+,-,/");
        if (uservalue == "*")
        {
            Console.Write("Resultat= " + a * b);
        }
        else if (uservalue == "+")
        {
            Console.Write("Resultat= " + (a + b));
        }
        else if (uservalue == "-")
        {
            Console.Write("Resultat= " + (a - b));
        }
        else if (uservalue == "/")
        {
            Console.Write("Resultat= " + (a / b));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
    }
```